# Not able to add buttons and text fields to my android app

Tags: android, user-interface

Ok so I followed the Android Tutorials at the developer.android.com to build my first app. So to create a simple user interface I added a button and text field given in the tutorial. But when I run it on my phone, I don't see the buttons or text field.

```
    package com.example.lookforbuttons;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            TextView tv= new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Buttons");
            setContentView(tv);
        }
    }
```

The .xml file where I describe the layout is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

and the strings.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">Buttons</string>
        <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
        <string name="button_send">Send</string>
        <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
        <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    </resources>
```

The target android version is 4.03 since I am testing it on 4.03 phone. When I run this I only "Buttons" printed and no button or text field. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `setContentView` twice. When you do this, the second time is what you will see on the screen because it will overwrite whatever `layout` you called in the first call to `setContentView()`. So since you call

```
setContentView(tv);
```

last you only have the `TextView`. Remove that line and you should see your `EditText` and your `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

In your  code you are setting `setContentview()` twice. That means you are changing the `layout` which contains `Button` and `TextView` with second `setContentview()`. 
If you want to dynamically add new `TextView` to your `layout`. Remove the second `setContentView()` and assign an `id` to your `LinearLayout` in xml. Then find it in your Java code and say `linearlayout.add(textview)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/lv"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>


Linearlayout lv=(Linearlayout) findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.add(textview);
```